# ViewPager inside RecycleView Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, fragment

I tried to add **Viewpager** inside **RecycleView** item, then I created the adapter for the recycle view and I created a Pager Adapter that extends from **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** class inside the the adapter.

Just the first item of the recycle works fine, but the rest items of recycle view do not show the view pager.

When I Log inside the Pager Adapter I can see all the fragment position.

When I scroll horizontally inside any pager of any recycle view item I can see the Log statement, but nothing appear on the screen.

Could any one help me in that case ?
Here is my code

```
public class RentCategoryItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RentCategoryItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<RentCategoryItem> categoryItems;
    ArrayList<MyPagerAdapter> pagerAdapters = new ArrayList<>();
    /*ArrayList<ViewPager> pagerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<MyPagerAdapter> myPagerAdapterArrayList = new ArrayList<>();*/
    public RentCategoryItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RentCategoryItem> categoryItems) {
        mContext = context;
        this.categoryItems = categoryItems;
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) mContext;
        for (int i = 0; i < categoryItems.size(); i++) {
            pagerAdapters.add(new MyPagerAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), categoryItems.get(i).catItems));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemLayoutView;

        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rent_category_item,parent, false);

        RentCategoryItemAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new RentCategoryItemAdapter.ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.catName.setText(categoryItems.get(position).catName);
        //AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) mContext;
        //holder.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), categoryItems.get(position).catItems);
        holder.pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapters.get(position));
        Log.d("Tag", pagerAdapters.get(position).getCount() + " position " + position);
        /*holder.mPagerAdapter = myPagerAdapterArrayList.get(position);
        holder.pager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapterArrayList.get(position));*/
        int margin = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10*16, mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        holder.pager.setPageMargin(-margin);
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
        TextView catName;
        ViewPager pager;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            pager = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            catName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
            /*pagerArrayList.add(new ViewPager(mContext));
            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) mContext;
            myPagerAdapterArrayList.add(new MyPagerAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager()));*/
        }
    }


    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        ArrayList<RentItem> items;
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<RentItem> items) {
            super(fm);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new RentCategoryForPagerFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("first_last", "first");
            bundle.putString("product_id", items.get(position).productId);
            bundle.putString("product_name", items.get(position).productName);
            bundle.putString("product_price", items.get(position).productPrice);
            bundle.putString("product_image", items.get(position).productImage);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            Log.d("Tag", "inside my pager adapter " + position);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is RentCategoryForPagerFragment class

```
public class RentCategoryForPagerFragment extends Fragment {

    String firstOrLast = "";
    ImageView productImage;
    TextView productName, productPrice;
    String productId;
    Button showDetailsButton;
    public RentCategoryForPagerFragment() {
        //firstOrLast = getArguments().getString("first_last");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rent_item_in_category_layout, container, false);
        productImage = rootView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        productName = rootView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        productPrice = rootView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        showDetailsButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.show_details_button);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String imageURL = bundle.getString("product_image");
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imageURL).into(productImage);
        productId = bundle.getString("product_id");
        productName.setText(bundle.getString("product_name"));
        productPrice.setText(bundle.getString("product_price"));
        showDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
  }
```

The result I got in this 
[image]

Comment: IS `RentCategoryForPagerFragment` blank or it has a custom layout??

Comment: show your `RentCategoryForPagerFragment` class

Comment: @Santanu Sur check now

Comment: do you have internet permission ?

Comment: try log the data after `getArguments()` then report..

Comment: Yeah, I can see that everything is ok but just in the first item only.

Comment: Then the first item is showing in the screen right?

Comment: Am gonna upload an image.

Comment: whats the problem the image isnt loading right?

Comment: I can see it even when I change the browser.

Comment: do one thing give background color to white to the layout `rent_item_in_category_layout` give the parent layout of the fragment `Color.White` and report...

Comment: What about the first item ?? why does it work perfect without any colors ?

Comment: the first item is getting the data maybe ...but for the rest there may be empty data..

Comment: Any **Fragment** in any pager can get its data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. I was using the wrong class because it sound that **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** and **FragmentPagerAdapter** Classes do not  serve my idea.
So You should extend from **PagerAdapter** instead to implement more than one pager in the same screen. And you should override some methods to complete it.

I hope this answer helps someone in someday.